# Prevent fast button clicking for backend

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm creating a web page where a button is located in it. When the user press the button, my Javascript uses AJAX to call my backend which asks my database and gets some pictures to put on the screen.
It's something like this (pseudo-code):

```
// JS event
button.on('click', function(){
    // Here my AJAX calling
    $.post(callMyBackend, {
       foo: bar // Parameters
    }, function (responseText) {
       // Here goes more stuff...
    });
});
```

Everything works perfectly, but I want to prevent user doesn't abuse by clicking on the button too fast. So, if the user clicks 3 times very fast I would like that the calling to my backend would happens once (not 3 times) and return the results **only for the last call** (caution, the last one, no the first one!).

How could I resolve that?

Comment: I see answers that solve the problem if I would like to obey the first call. I don't want that. I want to obey the LAST call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `progress`
variable:

```
// JS event
var progress = false;

button.on('click', function() {
    if (progress) {
        return;
    }
    progress = true;
    // Here my AJAX calling
    $.post(callMyBackend, {
        foo: bar // Parameters
    }, function(responseText) {

        progress = false;
        // Here goes more stuff...
    });
});
```

of course i recommend you add js code for change style of your button e.x. "disabled"

Answer (score 2):

```
// JS event
button.on('click', function( this ){
if ( !this.hasAttribute( 'data-noclick' ) ) {
    // Here my AJAX calling
    this.setAttribute( 'data-noclick', 'true' );
    $.post(callMyBackend, {
       foo: bar // Parameters
    }, function (responseText) {
       // Here goes more stuff...
    this.removeAttribute( 'data-noclick' );
    });
});
```

Comment: This solves the problem if I would like to obey the first call. I don't want that. I want to obey the LAST call.

Answer (score 1):

You may disable the button as first action. When you need or after a timeout you can enable again the button:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    this.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(ele) {
        ele.disabled = false;
    }, 1000, this)
    return; // ......
    // Here my AJAX calling
    $.post(callMyBackend, {
        foo: bar // Parameters
    }, function (responseText) {
        // Here goes more stuff...
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This solves the problem if I would like to obey the first call. I don't want that. I want to obey the LAST call.